# Extract text from a PDF with regex

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, pdf

I have a pdf that looks like this:[image]

and I would like to extract the numbered items into a dictionary:

```
output = {'01': 'Agriculture and related service activities',
          '011': 'Growing crops, market gardening and horticulture'...}
```

Currently I am using tika to extract the text from the pdf. But I now need a regex expression to extract the numbered items out of the content. 
How do I do this?

```
from tika import parser
raw = parser.from_file(path)
text = raw['content']
regex = ???
match = re.findall(regex, text, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

The text variable contains the text of the document. It looks like this:

u"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nSTATISTICS SINGAPORE - Singapore Standard Industrial Classification, 2015\n\n\nSection A: Agriculture and Fishing\n\nSSIC 2015 Industry SSIC 2010\n\nSECTION A AGRICULTURE AND FISHING\n\n01 AGRICULTURE AND RELATED SERVICE ACTIVITIES\n\n011 GROWING OF CROPS, MARKET GARDENING AND HORTICULTURE\n\n0111 Growing of Food Crops (Non-Hydroponics)\n01111 Growing of leafy and fruit vegetables 01111\n01112 Growing of mushrooms 01112\n01113 Growing of root crops 01113......"

Comment: You may use: `regex = r'(?m)^\d+\s+\S+'` and you don't need `DOTALL`

Comment: What is in `text` variable?

Comment: @labjunky: Did that regex pattern work for you?

Comment: @ anubhava thanks, it returns the number and the first word, but not the words after that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'^' In the front of the regex might not work. Try the code below.

```
regex = '([\d]+).+?([a-zA-Z].+)'#(\d.+|$)'
match = re.findall(regex, s)
print(match)

Output : [('2015', 'Industry SSIC 2010'),
 ('01', 'AGRICULTURE AND RELATED SERVICE ACTIVITIES'),
 ('011', 'GROWING OF CROPS, MARKET GARDENING AND HORTICULTURE'),
 ('0111', 'Growing of Food Crops (Non-Hydroponics)'),
 ('01111', 'Growing of leafy and fruit vegetables 01111'),
 ('01112', 'Growing of mushrooms 01112'),
 ('01113', 'Growing of root crops 01113......')]
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
regex = ^([\d]+).+?([a-zA-Z].+?)(\d.+|$)
```